# WPF DataGrid - find column of clicked item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with CheckBoxes in the headers.
When a Checkbox is clicked, I want to know the index of it's column. All I found on Google was refering to cells being clicked, not header items. Even though I can see while debuging that dep IS DataGridColumnHeader, the while loop does not exit.

The Xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,-7,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,0,5,0" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.Day1Cb, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Click="HeaderCheckBox_Click"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Bla.Day1}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Day1}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And the CodeBehind:

```
private void HeaderCheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;  
    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader)) 
    {
       dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
       return;
    if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
    {
       DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = dep as DataGridColumnHeader;
       // do something
    }       
    int columnIndex = NavDataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c == dep).DisplayIndex;       
}
```

Thanks

Comment: By using this code are you able to get which cell is selected or not?

Comment: This code work if the checkbox is in a row cell. Since in this case, it is in the header, it doesnt work.

Comment: but from your code it seems to be in the cell.

Comment: Why don't you use the `sender` instead of the `e.OriginalSource` and see if this will get you the desired results.